# Cannot refresh or writing manually the url with react-router

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, react-router-dom, winscp

I used BrowserRouter with his basename, my server is WINSCP, the routes works correctly but, when I refresh it or writing it manually, I get :

[image]

My App.js is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {  BackTop } from 'antd';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Agenda from './components/Agenda/Agenda';
import Planning from './components/Planning/Planning';
import CreerActivite from './components/CreerActivite/CreerActivite';
import TypesRDV from './components/TypesRDV/TypesRDV';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter  basename="/ReactCalendar">
          <Header/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Planning} />

            <Route exact path="/creerActivite" component={CreerActivite} />
            <Route exact path="/typesRDV" component={TypesRDV} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <BackTop />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

On my package.json, I have `"homepage": "https://dev/ReactCalendar"` and my folder on WINSCP is `/dev/ReactCalendar/`

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is your server does not know what to serve when you hit that URL. There are multiple approaches to solving your problem. I'll suggest the easiest approach here.

Replace `BrowserRouter` with `HashRouter`.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HashRouter  basename="/ReactCalendar">
          <Header/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Planning} />

            <Route exact path="/creerActivite" component={CreerActivite} />
            <Route exact path="/typesRDV" component={TypesRDV} />
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
        <BackTop />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And obviously, don't forget to import `HashRouter` from 'react-router-dom'.

**You can view other approaches here:**
 [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: I get Attempted `import error: 'HashRouter' is not exported from 'react-router'.`

Comment: import it from `react-router-dom` @CodeLover

Comment: Just to complete this answer... React Router only controls what happens inside the app flow (links, redirect...) by using the' History API'. But when you touch the url manually React Router is not in control anymore, unless you use the HashRouter or some other generally more complex solutions.

Comment: I found a funny issue with HashRouter: The first time I type in the url it works ok, but if I type the same thing again it does a whole reload of the app.
For example being in `locahost:3000/` I type `locahost:3000/test` which does not exist, then HashRouter does not reload the page. But if try to send the same request again `locahost:3000/test` the app reloads...
I wonder why...  